# jquery fancy box don't pop up image

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

i want to show images on click using jquery fancy box plugin.

my images are coming from an api call.

```
 @foreach (var i in imageUrlList)
        {

            <a href="@i" class="star">
                <img src="@i" />
            </a>
        }
```

in the above code, @i has an url like:

```
http://api.mysite.com/Assignment/GetAssignmentPic?userGuid=002536&pictureID=102001
```

when I click on the image, it just downloads the image. It doesn't show up in the modal box.

BUT, if I put an image location which is in my program, it works as it should.

```
 @foreach (var i in imageUrlList)
        {

            <a href="@i" class="star">
                <img src="@i" />
            </a>
            <a href="~/Images/icons/bronzeStar.png" class="star"><img src="~/Images/icons/goldStar.png" /></a>
        }
```

in the above code, the second link works fine. So i am guessing getting the image from api call is not working here.

so is there any workaround..did anybody face this problem before ?

Comment: http://fancybox.net/faq ==>No.6  -or- http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab ==> No.5

Comment: it worked...thanks a lot. if you write it as an answer, i can accept that.